# Why datepicker flicker in React when focus in input field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

Could someone please tell me why datepicker flickers in React when focus in input field?

I am using this date picker in my demo

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/semantic-ui-calendar-react
```

but it **flickers on focus** or in other words when I focus to input field its first show on top and then come down below input field, why?
Here is my code

> https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-hill-mpurn

```
<div style={{ position: "absolute", top: 100, left: 100 }}>
        <DateInput
          name="date"
          placeholder="Date"
          value={date}
          popupPosition="right"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
</div>
```

Any update ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has a default animation of `scale`. You can turn it off by passing the prop `animation={false} like the following.

```
<DateInput
          name="date"
          placeholder="Date"
          value={date}
          popupPosition="right"
          onChange={handleChange}
          animation={false}
        />
```

CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/hloid

Comment: @suthan-bala Boolean value produces warning "Failed prop type: Invalid prop `animation` supplied to `Transition`." I just pass empty string animation={''} to get rid of this in errors console.

Comment: @suthan-bala any idea how to deal with this implementation in tsx files. I'm getting a compile-time error for the above fix, https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-calendar-reactissue-6mzgf