# semantic-ui-calendar-react flicker in .tsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

The calendar is flickering Using DateInput in .tsx files

Tried fixing the issue by [Why datepicker flicker in React when focus in input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57618248/why-datepicker-flicker-in-react-when-focus-in-input-field)

App1.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { DateInput } from "semantic-ui-calendar-react";
import "./styles.css";
import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css";

export default function App1() {
  const [date, setDate] = useState("");
  const handleChange = (event, { name, value }) => {
    setDate(value);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>
        App1.tsx - Flicker Fixed after using animation=false but getting build
        error
      </p>
      <div>
        <DateInput
          name="date"
          placeholder="Date"
          value={date}
          popupPosition="top right"
          onChange={handleChange}
          animation={false}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This throws error `Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'SemanticTRANSITIONS'`

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-calendar-reactissue-6mzgf?file=/src/App1.tsx)

Also, I tried to set the `duration` property to 0. This works intermittently when there is one DateInput, but I have multiple controls on the page if one of them is open and I open another one, the second one flickers.

If there is any other fix for the flickering, please let me know.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) to any third party site.

Comment: The links are of StackOverflow and code sandbox only.

Comment: Same comment. You are required to post your code **within the question** and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) to any third party site.

Comment: Updated. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue by wrapping the `DateInput` inside a js component and consuming that component from the `tsx` file.

Set `animation={''}` for fixing the issue as `animation={false}` gives console errors.